# Evitar redireccionamiento del SERVLET en lenguaje de programacion JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, jsp

Buen día, la situación es la siguiente: tengo una ventana modal de bootstrap donde inserto información a la base de datos (PostgreSQL), ésta acción se realiza desde un `botón input` y un `onclick="valida_envia2()"` que se encuentran dentro del modal

Ésta función se encuentra en el jsp:

```
function valida_envia2() {

                if (document.f2.producto.value.length === 0) {
                    alert("Ingresar Nombre de Producto")
                    document.f2.producto.focus()
                    return 0;
                }
                if (document.f2.precio.value.length === 0) {
                    alert("Ingresar Precio")
                    document.f2.precio.focus()
                    return 0;
                }

                alert("DATOS GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE")

                document.f2.submit();
            }
```

estos datos se ingresan en el siguiente **modal**:

```
<div class="container">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Cambio de Costos</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form name="f2" action="../cCambiocostos" method="POST" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
                                        <fieldset>

                                            <fieldset>

                                                <center>
                                                    <table width="800">

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                                <br><br><label>Producto</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" class="input" value="" size="30"/>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                                <br><br><label>Precio con Descuento</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="preciodes" id="preciodes" value=" " size="15">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>Precio</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="" size="15">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>% Desc. 1</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="des_uno" id=" des_uno" value="" size="15"> 
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>% Desc. 2</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="des_dos" id=" des_dos" value="" size="15"> 
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>% Desc. 3</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="des_tres" id=" des_tres" value="" size="15"> 
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                                <br><br><input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="valida_envia2()">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                                <br><br><input type="button" value="Cancelar">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </center>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>




<div class="container">

                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form name="f2" action="../cCambiocostos" method="POST" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <%
                                                modelo.cambioC cCosto = (modelo.cambioC) session.getAttribute("cambioCost");
                                                String nombrePro = cCosto.getNombre();
                                                String precios = String.valueOf(cCosto.getPrecio());
                                                String desc_uno = String.valueOf(cCosto.getDes_uno());
                                                String desc_dos = String.valueOf(cCosto.getDes_dos());
                                                String desc_tres = String.valueOf(cCosto.getDes_tres());
                                                String PreCDes = String.valueOf(cCosto.getPrecioCDes());
                                            %>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <legend>Cambio de Costos</legend>
                                                <center>
                                                    <table width="800">

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                                <br><br><label>Producto</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" class="input" value="<%=nombrePro%>" size="30"/>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                                <br><br><label>Precio con Descuento</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="preciodes" id="preciodes" value="<%=PreCDes%>" size="15">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>Precio</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="<%=precios%>" size="15" >
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>% Desc. 1</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="des_uno" id=" des_uno" value="<%=desc_uno%>" size="15"> 
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>% Desc. 2</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="des_dos" id=" des_dos" value="<%=desc_dos%>" size="15"> 
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <br><br><label>% Desc. 3</label>
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="des_tres" id=" des_tres" value="<%=desc_tres%>" size="15"> 
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                    </table>
                                                </center>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

el modelo de programación es MVC por lo tanto tengo un modelo y controlador:

**MODELO:**

```
package modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 *
 * @
 */
public class mCambiocostos {

    int idCambiocostos;
    String nombreproducto;
    double precio;
    double descuentounopro;
    double descuentodospro;
    double descuentotrespro;
    double preciocdes;

    public mCambiocostos() {

    }

    public static int getIdCambiocostos() {
        int claveCambCost = 0;
        try {
            modelo.conexion obj1 = new modelo.conexion();
            Connection conexion = obj1.conection();
            Statement st = conexion.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select ultimoregistrotcambiocosto();");

            while (rs.next()) {
                claveCambCost = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            conexion.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }

        return claveCambCost;

    }

    public String getNombreproducto() {
        return nombreproducto;
    }

    public void setNombreproducto(String nombreproducto) {
        this.nombreproducto = nombreproducto;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public double getDescuentounopro() {
        return descuentounopro;
    }

    public void setDescuentounopro(double descuentounopro) {
        this.descuentounopro = descuentounopro;
    }

    public double getDescuentodospro() {
        return descuentodospro;
    }

    public void setDescuentodospro(double descuentodospro) {
        this.descuentodospro = descuentodospro;
    }

    public double getDescuentotrespro() {
        return descuentotrespro;
    }

    public void setDescuentotrespro(double descuentotrespro) {
        this.descuentotrespro = descuentotrespro;
    }

    public double getPreciocdes() {
        return preciocdes;
    }

    public void setPreciocdes(double preciocdes) {
        this.preciocdes = preciocdes;
    }
```

El siguiente Modelo se utiliza para realizar la operación que calcula el porcentaje de descuento.

```
package modelo;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class cambioC {
    String nombre;
    double precio, des_uno, des_dos, des_tres, PrecioCDes;

    public cambioC() {
    }

    public cambioC(String nombre,double precio, double des_uno, double des_dos, double des_tres, double PrecioCDes) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.des_uno = des_uno;
        this.des_dos = des_dos;
        this.des_tres = des_tres;
        this.PrecioCDes = PrecioCDes;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public double getDes_uno() {
        return des_uno;
    }

    public void setDes_uno(double des_uno) {
        this.des_uno = des_uno;
    }

    public double getDes_dos() {
        return des_dos;
    }

    public void setDes_dos(double des_dos) {
        this.des_dos = des_dos;
    }

    public double getDes_tres() {
        return des_tres;
    }

    public void setDes_tres(double des_tres) {
        this.des_tres = des_tres;
    }

    public double getPrecioCDes() {
        return PrecioCDes;
    }

    public void setPrecioCDes(double PrecioCDes) {
        this.PrecioCDes = PrecioCDes;
    }

}
```

y finalmente el **SERVLET:**

```
package controlador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import modelo.cambioC;
import modelo.mCambiocostos;

/**
 *
 * @
 */
@WebServlet(name = "cCambiocostos", urlPatterns = {"/cCambiocostos"})
public class cCambiocostos extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            int claveCambCost = mCambiocostos.getIdCambiocostos();

            String NombProduc = request.getParameter("producto");

            String opproducto = request.getParameter("producto");
            String claveproduc = modelo.mProducto.getIdProducto(opproducto);

            String Preciopro = request.getParameter("precio");
            double var = Double.parseDouble(Preciopro);

            double var1=0, var2=0, var3=0, PrecioCDes = var;

            String DesUnopro = request.getParameter("des_uno");
            if (DesUnopro.equals("")||DesUnopro.equals("0.0")) {

            } else {
                var1 = Double.parseDouble(DesUnopro);
                PrecioCDes = var - ((var * var1) / 100);
            }

            String DesDospro = request.getParameter("des_dos");

            if (DesDospro.equals("")||DesDospro.equals("0.0")) {

            } else {
                var2 = Double.parseDouble(DesDospro);
                PrecioCDes = PrecioCDes - ((PrecioCDes * var2) / 100);
            }
            String DesTrespro = request.getParameter("des_tres");
            if (DesTrespro.equals("")||DesTrespro.equals("0.0")) {

            } else {
                var3 = Double.parseDouble(DesTrespro);

                PrecioCDes = PrecioCDes - ((PrecioCDes * var3) / 100);
            }

            cambioC Datos = new cambioC();
            Datos.setNombre(opproducto);
            Datos.setPrecio(var);
            Datos.setDes_uno(var1);
            Datos.setDes_dos(var2);
            Datos.setDes_tres(var3);
            Datos.setPrecioCDes(PrecioCDes);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("cambioCost", Datos);
            String consulta = "INSERT INTO cambiocostos(\n"
                    + "            idcamcosto, codigointerno,nombreproducto, preciopro, descuentounopro, descuentodospro, descuentotrespro, preciocondescuento)\n"
                    + "    VALUES (" + claveCambCost + ",'" + claveproduc + "','" + NombProduc + "'," + var + "," + var1 + "," + var2 + "," + var3 + "," + PrecioCDes + ")";

            modelo.conexion obj1 = new modelo.conexion();
            obj1.registro(consulta);
            response.sendRedirect("Compras/cambiodecosto.jsp");
        }
    }
```

Este código ya me permite ingresar la información a la base de datos ahora necesito ayuda para que me envie al siguiente modal que se ve el código y posteriormente evitar que el servlet me redireccione a otro jsp.(no realize otra acción el servlet, lenguaje de programación JSP)

No se si esto sea importante, pero se me paso comentar que ese modal se genera por medio de un boton que se encuentra dentro de una tabla

function agregar() {

```
            cont++;
            var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '"onclick="seleccionar(this.id) "><div id="contenido" ><form><td><input type="text" name="codigointerno[]" id="codigointerno' + cont + '" size="10" readonly="true" disabled="true"/></td>';
            fila += '<td><input type="text" name="producto[]" id="producto' + cont + '" size="30" onchange="combodetallecompra(' + cont + ')"/></td>'
            fila += '<td><select name="presentacion[]" id="presentacion' + cont + '">';
            fila += sel_tipopresentacion;
            fila += '< /select></td>';
            fila += '<td><input name="Costo_ult_compra[]" id="Costo_ult_compra' + cont + '"/></td><td><input name="Costo_prome[]" id="Costo_prome' + cont + '"/></td>';
            fila += '<td><input type="text" name="Costo_lis[]" id="Costo_lis' + cont + '" size="20"/></td><td><input type="text" name="Cantidad_Ord[]" id="Cantidad_Ord' + cont + '"></td>';
            fila += '<td> <input type="text" name="Unidad_grat[]"  id="Unidad_grat' + cont + '" size="10"/></td><td><input type="text" name="costo_sin_iva[]"  id="costo_sin_iva' + cont + '" size="10" disabled="true"/></td>';
            fila += '<td> <input type="text" name="Total_rec[]" id="Total_rec' + cont + '" size="10" disabled="true"/></td>';
            fila += '<td> <input type="text" name="Importe_bruto[]" id="Importe_bruto' + cont + '" size="10" disabled="true"/></td>';
            fila += '<td><input type="text" name="Importe_iva[]" id="Importe_iva' + cont + '" class="input" size="10" disabled="true"/></td>';
            fila += '<td><input type="text" name="Importe_total[]" id="Importe_total ' + cont + '" size="8" disabled="true"/></td>\n\\n'
            fila += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Costo</button></td></form></div></tr>';
            $('#tablaordcomp').append(fila);
        }
```

y efectivamente al enviar el submit() el servlet pide de forma inmediata una vista, por ello requeriro que solo se cierre el modal y continuar dentro de esa tabla.

Comment: Edita tu publicación y pon el código correcto del servlet, encierra entre bloques de código todo lo que sea código e investiga ajax o peticiones asynchronas. Crea una un método en el servlet que te retorne un string, cuando quieras guardar hazlo en ese método, si se guardó correctamente guarda en el string que retorna una palabra que puedas ubicar para validar si se guardó o no correctamente al terminar la petición ajax (usa jquery), en el complete del ajax haces la validación y si se guardó correctamente entonces muestras tu siguiente modal.

Comment: Te agradezco user2930137 pero si no es mucha molestia me podras explicar con manzanas la verdad es que soy novata en esto y una disculpa por lo del SERVLET

Comment: Te lo pongo en respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BUEN DIA A TODOS LES AGRADEZCO SU AYUDA Y LA SOLUCION A LO QUE NECESITABA FUE LA SIGUIENTE:

DENTRO DE LA TABLA SE CAMBIO LA LINEA DEL BOTÓN QUE SE MUESTRA A CONTINUACIÓN

```
        fila += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Costo</button></td></form></div></tr>';
```

POR LA SIGUIENTE LINEA

```
        fila += '<td><a href="cambiodecosto.jsp" target="_blank"onClick="window.open(this.href, this.target","width=300,height=400"); return false;> Costos </a></td></form></div></tr>';
```

DE ESTA MANERA EL JSP TRABAJA DE MANERA INDEPENDIENTE FACILITANDO REALIZAR MÁS FUNCIONES ESPERO ESTO LE SEA ÚTIL A ALGUIEN MÁS.

SALUDOS Y NUEVAMENTE GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada tengo una observación,
La primera, cuando usas un form y un .submit(), lo que hace es redireccionar a ese action de tu servlet,por consecuencia lo que se espera cargues una vista.

Ahora podría sugerir un par de cosas, no estoy seguro si pueda funcionar jeje, pero podrías intentar, luego de tu .submit() por un return false, y así detienes que continué el flujo.

Lo segundo, podrías hacer también tu petición con Ajax, así seria más sencillo evitar el re-direccionamiento.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Migue y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y puedes seguir estos **[pasos para elaborar una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Saludos.

Comment: Hola!!! Migue, mira ya intente lo del return false y no funciona, sin embargo tengo duda y es si la peticion de ajax se implemente en el servlet? por otro lado es cierto lo que tu me comentas el SERVLET tenemos esta linea de codigo que es la que nos redirecciona  response.sendRedirect("Compras/cambiodecosto.jsp"); y no se si me puedas ayudar con codigo para cambiarlo en esa area.        Gracias Migue

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza ajax. La documentación la encuentras aquí: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Tu petición quedaría más o menos así:

```
$("#idFormulario").submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize(); //O algo así era
    $.ajax({
       url: '/urlDelServlet',
       data: data,
       type: 'POST', //o GET
       error: function() { //En caso que haya error por parte de ajax
          $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
       },
       success: function(data) { //En caso que no lo haya y todo vaya bien
          //data trae la respuesta del servlet. Digamos que en el servlet regresaste un "Ok" si todo se procesó correctamente.
          if(data == "Ok"){
             alert("Todo salió bien, ahora voy a mostrar el otro modal");
             //Cerrar modal 1
             //Poner aquí el código para mostrar el siguiente modal
          } else {
            alert("Algo salió mal en el servlet, no se guardó la info");
          }
       }

    });
});
```

Lo único que cambias en tu servlet es validar si salió todo bien y retornar un "Ok" para cuando salga bien u otra cosa para cuando salga mal. Para poder escribirle una respuesta a ajax necesitas implementar estas líneas en código en vez de tu redirect:

```
 response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(variableDelaRespuestaQueContieneOkUOtraCosa);
```

Si aún tienes dudas puedes leer este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Answer (score 0):

@Jazz No, el ajax lo agregas en tu jsp, solo necesitas invocarlo desde el evento click de tu botón, la sintaxis es de esta manera:

```
$.ajax({ 
url: 'nombre del servlet', 
type: 'POST', // tambien puede ser de tipo GET, depende de ti
data: {parametro1: valor1, parametro2: valor2}, //si tu método recibe parámetros los pones con esa sintaxis, si no tienes parámetros lo dejas vacío'
success: function( respuesta ){ 
  // Si tu petición se concreto bien, aquí puedes validar tu respuesta o mostrar un mensaje o realizar otra acción 
 }, 
  error: function(error){ // si hubo algún error entra aquí 
 } 
});
```

y como esto se realiza de manera dinámica (en segundo plano), incluso puedes poner algún tipo de animación en lo que ejecutas tu evento.

e inclusive de manera alternativa te puedes apoyar en el siguiente enlace https://jarroba.com/ajax-con-jsp-y-servelts/

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Agradezco la ayuda solo que no detiene el servlet, este me continua solicitando una vista  y no se se un exista algo diferente puesto que solo requiero que el model realize como tal la operacion pero el servlet ya no requierea de esta linea de codigo      response.sendRedirect("Compras/cambiodecosto.jsp");    ya que es esta la que me redirecciona al siguienten jsp para poder efectuar el proceso. Espero no sea mucho pedir gracias Migue